# Slow Performance on Exported Hyper-V VMs

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I have an Windows Server 2012 environment with Hyper-V virtualization. My VMs were running very well but my machine was running low on disk space.

After buying an new HDD and installing it on my machine, I exported all my machines to the new HDD, imported again and started them all.

After that, I could notice that all VMs were running with a very bad performance... local tasks running very slow, bad network traffic, slow even copying files. Looking at performance monitors (task manager, nagios, etc), the VMs are not using all resources... they barely are using it.

So, I moved one of the VMs back to the original VHD and this VM worked great again.

I need to migrate this VM's to the new HDD, but I need to deal with this performance issue.

Do you have any tip to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Sounds to me like your newer drives are just slower.

Comment: The new drive have better specs than the older one :(

Old drive: "Western Digital WD RE4 WD5003ABYX 500GB 7200 RPM 64MB Cache SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive Bare Drive"

New drive:  "Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003 1TB 7200 RPM 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive Bare Drive"

Comment: Not sure where you get better from. The new disc is larger with the same characteristics and this OBVIOUSLY slower than the old one. Though it should not be THAT much slower, it is NOT better. Larger discs just mean same IO budget for more space = slower operation.

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating the obvious.. check the basics first.

What disk/s do you have in your old config, and what disk did you add? What configuration is set up in terms of arrays? Are you using RAID cards on on-board buses for the old / new disks?

What is your OS / Data disk setup pre- and post-install?

Comment: My server is an Dell PowerEdge T320 with a RAID controller PERC H310. Despite my RAID controller, I am not using any RAID, only two HDDs attached on server.

My original HDD is an "Western Digital WD RE4 WD5003ABYX 500GB 7200 RPM 64MB Cache SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive Bare Drive"
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136697

The new HDD is an "Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003 1TB 7200 RPM 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive Bare Drive"
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148840

Same setup for both, original on C: and the new on D:

Comment: Did you test by plugging the second hard drive into the second 4Xmini-SAS connector on the controller?

Comment: Im using the second 8x 3.5-inch hot-plug SATA drive bay.

Comment: At first hand it does seem odd. I suggest firmware upgrades on the PERC and even the hard drive (I have had that once before where a firmware fix increased performance). I'm thinking of other options..